# session lost when mobile browser wakeup from sleep

Tags: php, session

i am having a strange problem. in my mobile site after the user put the phone to sleep for about 30 minutes and try to re-use the website the session seems to be lost.

altering `session.cookie_lifetime` does not seems to have any effect on this.

can i solve this problem by increasing the value of `session.gc_maxlifetime` ?

here is the full code

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.private.net");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", 60*60*24);
session_set_cookie_params(60*60*24*7, "/", COOKIE_DOMAIN);
session_start();
```

Comment: I have the same problem i'm thinking to store session details into the database.

Comment: i have taken an interim step to use a cookie to maintain user info and re-login when session is lost. not a very secure approach IMHO. i am curious what are the standard methods used for this problem.

Comment: Storing it somewhere else does not help if the same garbage collector kicks in. If you need a longer session lifetime, yes, increase the gc_maxlifetime. If you're on shared hosting, be sure your session.save_dir isn't shared with other sites, as the 'lowest' configured lifetime would win / clean up prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

From your provided code I assume that you are using the default Session Store, this means the session data is stored in the filesystem and the cookie only contains the `PHPSESSID` (Session ID). 
In order to store the session data longer when using filesystem, you need to set the [`session.gc_maxlifetime`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) configuration accordingly.
You can do this either in the `php.ini` or with [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php):

`ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", 60*60*24*7);`

If you want to increase the Cookie lifetime (it defaults to 0, means that it is deleted when the browser is closed) you can set the [`session.cookie_lifetime`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime), or use [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) again, or just do it like you are doing it in your example.